# prohibit inline assembly in g++ (gcc) or clang (llvm)

Tags: gcc, assembly, g++, clang

There are problem-solving sites like [topcoder.com](http://topcoder.com), [SPOJ](http://spoj.pl).
I'd like for similar use-case (people send me C++ program files) to do some restrictions.

One of those is:

- "is not allowed using in-line assembly"

How can I enforce such prohibition? Is there smarter way (like compiler flags? - but I haven't found any useful) than just searching phrases in source-code ?

I can restrict people to g++ or clang. Things are being done on Linux.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Restricting inline asm doesn't help much if you're worried about security.

Comment: @servn Ok. But I am not only worried about security, but fair C/C++ competition. I would like to prevent people from using asm, just because we decided about such rule. I want to automatize process of such policy. I understand it's not full solution and there is need for more. Thanks for pointing it out. Maybe you have some more ideas ? If interested in security, please check out my other questions : [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/users/4077?tab=questions)

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
% gcc -Dasm=error -D__asm__=error
```

Comment: How does it work? I understand it makes macros with names: `asm`, `__asm__`. Is shadowing build-in keywords allowed? Can I do the same for prohibiting function calls (like "system()") ? Is it safe solution - no way to workaround it (hack) ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki the preprocessor gets its hand on the code before the compiler, and has no knowledge of keywords, so yes, it can change them.  It can be worked around - a simple `#undef asm` in the code would do it.  That would be easy to find though.

Comment: Each time I look at [The International Obfuscated C Code Contest ](http://www.ioccc.org/) I am more and more afraid there are ways to obfuscate things, like `#undef asm`.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki yes, it's hard to use technology to enforce policy.  There are _always_ ways around it.

Comment: According to answer, I haven't idea that I can shadow keywords with preprocessor. Thanks a lot - It gives new possibilities :).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for the `-fno-asm` flag.

Although it looks like that just does `asm` rather than also doing `__asm__` so maybe add on a `-D__asm__=something_that_will_error`.

Also look at `-fno-gnu-keywords` for turning off `asm` in C++.

Comment: gcc 4.4.6 manpage under Linux implies this doesn't disable `__asm__`.